# two event functionality in one php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I'm new to php and jquery. Pardon my php vocabulary.

I have two events in my js file.

1) onsubmit: submits the user entered text to result.php which queries database and displays result. (result.php?name=xyz)

2) onkeyup: makes an ajax call to the same result.php which queries a url and gets json data.  (result.php?key=xyz)

My question is if I can check for isset($_GET['key']) in result.php, query url and return json and the rest of the php is not parsed.
Basically is there anything like return 0 as in case of C programming.

The question may seem silly, anyway I can have 2 different php files, but I want to know if it's possible.
Thanks in advance :)

```
<form action = "result.php" method = "get">
<input type = "text" id = "name" >
<input type = " submit">
</form>
<script>
$('#name').on('keyup',function (e){
   input_val = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url: "result.php?key=" + input_val,
      success: function(data){
      alert(data);
      }
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Show us some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand, you want to know a way to use *only one PHP script* being able to process either Ajax and "normal" (returning whole page) tasks.

So if yes, this can be easily achieve, using the following schema:

```
//... some initialization, if needed
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
  // ... do the job for creating the expected Ajax response, say $ajax_response
  echo $ajax_response;
  exit;
  // nothing else will happen in the current script execution
}
// otherwhise you can do all "normal" job here, as usual...
```

Comment: @Anusha Glad to help. So might you consider to accept my answer? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

From your question if i have understood properly ,  you want to return boolean from PHP to Ajax , you can just echo "success" or "failure" based on if condition , and catch that in ajax response and process it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit;` or `die();` to terminate php script. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php